# Access parent constructor in a parent namespace

Tags: php

I try to call the constructor of a parent class, which has the exact same name of the namespace:

```
namespace {
    class foo {
        public function __construct() {
            echo "foobar";
        }
    }
};

namespace foo {
    class bar {
        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }
    }
};
```

Can I(?, and if so - How to) call the parent constructor within the new namespace?

Comment: is the first one supposed to be namespace foo as well?

Comment: And is bar supposed to extend foo? Just wanted to make sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yes bar supposed to extend foo, but foo needs to be global (not `new \foo\foo()`, just `new \foo()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying that that class `\foo\bar` extends class `\foo` should be sufficient for `\foo\bar` to be able to access the constructor of `\foo`.

```
namespace foo
{
    class bar extends \foo
    {
        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }
    }

    $bar = new bar();  // prints foobar
}
```

Executable example at 3v4l.org: https://3v4l.org/1YkqY

Comment: I hope one day it will be easier to use namespace without `extends ...` in class :( Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm afraid I'm not sure what you mean, though. Were you thinking anything in a namespace `\foo` should automatically extend a class  `\foo`?

Comment: Unfortunately yes :( I thought `namespace` is also a way to extend classes without using `extends`, since i'm already inside and it will be easier to extend